# Qual a diferença entre element.push("value") e element[element.length]

Tags: javascript

Olá. Sempre que preciso adicionar um novo índice em um array utilizo o segundo método, porém vejo alguns usando o primeiro e não sei se há alguma diferença entre eles.

Answer (score 5):

O método `push` adiciona um valor ao array e retorna a nova quantidade de itens.

```
var navegadores = ["Google Chrome", "Firefox"];
navegadores.push("Opera");
// retorno:  3
```

A segunda forma que você costuma usar pega o tamanho total do array `navegadores.length` e atribui um valor naquela posição.

```
var navegadores = ["Google Chrome", "Firefox"];
navegadores[navegadores.length] = "Opera";
// retorno: Opera
```

É recomendável usar o push por já ser um método nativo pra essa função, além de que a sintaxe fica mais clara pra quem está lendo seu código.

Leitura recomendada: [MDN - Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)